# seo friendly url for codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, seo, friendly-url

We have a social networking web site for students. Our url looks like this `domain.com/student/145236` where **145236** is the roll number. We now have an option of doing something like this `domain.com/student/145236/student-name` but since google / search engines would prefer `domain.com/student-name/student/145236` we would like to do like this, but we are unable to do it, we tried doing this using routes `$route['(:any)/student/(:num)'] = 'student/$1';` but it shows 404 page, any help would be grateful :)

Answer (score 4):

This should be work for you:

```
$route['(:any)/student/(:num)'] = 'student/yourfunction/$1/$2';
```

Here `$1` is for ist param `(:any)` and 
`$2` is for second param `(:num)` .

For getting values from the URL inside the student controller you can use **CI Segments.**

Comment: actually it creates problem with other controllers like `welcome/school/14526` or `teacher/maths/145236`

Comment: @runningmark: i suggest u to use like `$route['student/(:any)/(:num)']`

Comment: you can also read it easily like Student >> Student Name >> ID @runningmark

Comment: that's what i'm now thinking of because segment 1 is i guess reserved for controller